# Find role based on list of permissions

Tags: users

Is there any way of finding the role given a list of permissions?

I.E.:

```
$permissions = array('administer content', 'access content');
$role        = find_related_roles();

// $role = array(4 => 'client')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
  $permissions = array('administer content', 'access content');
  $query = db_select('role', 'r')
    ->fields('r', array('name'));
  $alias = 'rp';
  foreach($permissions as $perm){
    $query->innerJoin('role_permission', $alias, 'r.rid='.$alias.'.rid');
    $query->condition($alias.'.permission', $perm);
    $alias = $alias . 'a';
  }
  $result = $query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('name');
```

It's doing separate inner joins with the role_permission table for each permission, to ensure that the role has all the permissions.